# Writing basic ping program with a menu. Every time I run the code it just loops the menu I wrote and I'm not exactly sure why. Thank you

Tags: python, nmap

Here is the code I wrote:

```
import nmap

def menu():
    print (30 * "-", "I hate the CIA", 30 * "-")
    print ("1. Ping")
    print ("2. ???")
    print ("3. ???")
menu()
choice = input("Enter your choice [1 - 3]: ")
if choice==1:
    input("Please choose your target: ")
    t = nmap.PortScanner()
    t.scan(hosts=input, arguments='-sP')
```

I know it's probably very messy and it's likely bad practice to write in "to-be functionalities" like I have done, but I'm pretty new to this and I'm willing to take it out if there is a better way. Perhaps the answer is clear to me, maybe not. Help is appreciated. Thanks all <3

Comment: Where do you store the output of line `input("Please choose your target: ")`? Why is the part `hosts=input` referencing `input` function?

Answer (score 0):

input() always return a string.

Try:

```py
...
if choice == '1':
   input("Please choose your target: ")
   ...
```

Alternatively if you want numerical values for 'choice', you can convert input string to integer:

```py
choice = int(input("Enter your choice [1 - 3]: "))
```

But this will fail if user types non-numerical value.

Comment: Thank, you this worked. There's still more errors to work out, but on the right path.